# Calculating the power of a rotor using two methods

Tags: power

I have been calculating the power required to accelerate a small solid rotor up to 2000 RPM using two different but equally valid methods of calculation, and yet they give different results by a factor of 2. Where am I going wrong?

I will lay out both methods:

The first is calculating the kinetic energy of the rotor at 2000 RPM and dividing that by the time to reach those revs, that being 22 seconds.

Method 1: P = KE/t = ½ I <sup>2</sup>/t

Rotor mass = 0.685 kg, radius: 0.055 m
so I = 0.001 kgm<sup>2</sup>

= 2000/60 x 2 = 209.5 rad/s,

∴ <sup>2</sup> = 43,920

P = 0.5 x 0.001 x 43,920 / 22 = 0.995 W

Method 2 is calculating the Torque and multiplying that by the angular velocity, where the Torque is derived from the inertia times the angular acceleration.

i.e. P = T  and T = I therefore P = I  = I<sup>2</sup>/t

I = 0.001 kgm<sup>2</sup> (from above)

= 2000/60 x 2 = 209.4 rad/s

= /t = (2000/60 x 2)/22 = 9.52 rad/s<sup>2</sup>

so T = 0.001 x 9.52 = 0.0095 Nm

and P = 0.0095 x 209.4 = 1.99 W

A factor of two different!

The only explanation I can come up with is that method 2 is a 'dynamic' calculation using angular acceleration and method 1 is not, being instead of sort of 'averaging' calculation; and so I should use the average time of (22-0)/2 = 11sec. So in effect, the KE of the rotor at 2000 RPM is derived from the area under the line as per the graphic and so it's half the area.

[image: Energy as integral of power graph]

That would bring the two answers in line with each other but I'm having difficulty justifying using the average time.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I've just edited your question an your equations are inconsistent.

In Method 1, you state the equation is P = ½Iω<sup>2</sup>/t

In Method 2, you state, P = Tω and that T = Iα therefore P = Iαω

you also state α = ω/t

Substituting this back into the final equation for Method 2, P = Iω<sup>2</sup>/t, which produces twice the value of the equation you used for Method 1 - it doesn't have the ½ that is in the equation for Method 1.

One of your equations is incorrect.

Comment: So Power is not 0.5 I ^2 but instead I ^2 ? If so then I will have to tell my source of their mistake :)

Comment: In Method 1, P is derived from KE/t and where the KE is 1/2 I ^2 so P must equal 1/2 I ^2/t. That being so then there must be something wrong with the equation in Method 2? Perhaps P = 1/2 T?

Comment: I have checked that P = T is correct so you can see my dilemma :|

Answer (score 1):

In your second equation, you are assuming that $\omega$ is constant even though it is not.  Both equations are assuming that power is constant, even though it is not.

Assuming constant torque for the interval $0 < t < t_{end}$:

$P(t) = T \omega(t)$

$\omega(t) = \alpha t$

The *energy* put into the flywheel in the interval is then

$$W = \int_0^{t_{end}} T\omega(t) dt = \int_0^{t_{end}} T\alpha t\ dt = \left . \frac 1 2 T\alpha t^2 \right |_0^{t_{end}} = \frac 1 2 T\alpha t_{end}^2$$

This is where your first equation comes from.  But it is not the *power*, which is always changing.

If you wanted to calculate the *average power* of the event, then you would calculate $W / t_{end}$.  That would be valid for, say, a plant that's always accelerating such wheels, and you need to know how much your energy expenditure will be.  It would be *totally invalid*, however, for sizing drive electronics for a motor to accelerate the wheel, which would need to be sized for the maximum power -- which happens right as $t \to t_{end}$.

Comment: The second half of the above is my response. There’s not enough space in this box.

Comment: I think you misunderstand how Stackexchange works.  It is not a discussion site; discussion in comments is only encouraged in furtherance of clarifying questions or answers, and discussion in answers isn't sensible, because then they wouldn't be answers.  Questions should be self-contained, and answers should respond to the question.  To the degree that your additional information in your proposed edits were clarifications **to your question**, then you should _edit that question_ with those clarifications.  Then _I_ may edit my answer to match your newly-improved question.